# FB Chat API - Authenticating X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM using Strophe

Tags: facebook, xmpp, strophe, facebook-chat, x-facebook-platform

I am trying to connect to FB Chat using the X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM authentication technique. I am currently using the Strophe library.

Everything else is done and working, I saved this bit for last (I knew it was going to be hard).

However Strophe only provides support for MD5 which I can't use as its a JS client. So instead I need to find a way to do a special Strophe connection.

I have seen the Strophe plugin at;

https://github.com/rubenjgarciab/turedsocial/blob/dc12d71339ad509c946b5de727f2d77999153b02/strophe-plugins/src/facebook.js

However this doesn't work since OAuth 2.0 enforcement. I'm confident to do the connection manually if I absolutely have to however I'm hoping somebody has already solved this problem.

At the very least could somebody tell me how to do the connection manually (as in the Strophe functions to bypass .connect(); and do it yourself).

Thanks
Andrew

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing rows 104-110 of this strophe facebook plugin by the following instructions under: "Authenticating with Facebook Platform" here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/

Mainly, IIt involves removing the session key and adding an access token param.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew,

Here is my fork with the proper changes. Good luck!

https://github.com/javierfigueroa/turedsocial

Comment: why does it asks for the App's secret key? on a web service where everyone is able to read it that's not smart to provide. (That aside of the fact that Facebook doesn't requires you to provide it)